# parsing html with regex - using capture and $1 parameter

Tags: html, regex, perl

i just want to say that i understand that you can't parse HTML with regexes. 
i get that.  you cannot parse HTML with regex.

I am just getting a few urls from a webpage.

the output is a little strange - there a a new line 
after the closing anchor tag.

```
<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=20193&Template=view&TableId
=1023"><B>26165</B></A>

<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=21811&Template=view&TableId
=1023"><B>28722</B></A>

<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22163&Template=view&TableId
 =1023"><B>29327</B></A>

<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22238&Template=view&TableId
=1023"><B>29450</B></A>
```

So i write this little script to make it neater.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings ;
my $list = "/tmp/rawurl_list";
open( my $filehandle ,"<", "$list") or die $!;
while (<$filehandle>) {
    s/\n//g;
    s/\<\/A\>/\n/g;
    print $_ ;
        if ($_ =~ /^<A HREF="(.*)"/) {
           print $1;
        }
}
```

and this is what i get

```
<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?  IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=20193&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>26165</B>
<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=21811&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>28722</B>
<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22163&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>29327</B>
<A HREF="tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22238&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>29450</B>
```

But i am havin trouble stripping off the \A HREF tag.

The HREF regex must be ok - it works on the one liner.

```
bash-3.00$ /casper/strip | perl -nle 'print /^<A\sHREF="(.*)"/'
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=20193&Template=view&TableId=1023
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=21811&Template=view&TableId=1023
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22163&Template=view&TableId=1023
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22238&Template=view&TableId=1023
```

i must be doing something wrong with the script - i need to learn why this does not strip off the html tags.  I am posting this because I run into this error all the time and just end up using the perl extract from the command line instead of withing a script. 
I am not learning past this.

Comment: You can parse html with regex, but there is other tools that are build to do this task.

Comment: are the replaces ok  - should they be dereferenced to something like $_ = s/\n//g;  or is that implied?  how could i make the logic of this script better and make it work.

Comment: `$_ =~` is implied.  (`$_ =` would do something very different.)

Comment: is the if statement ok - i think that is the issue - does it still have the ability to read from the while or is it just dangling off of the main  - waiting for input?  like the first two substitues strip off the new lines and the end tags - that should leave the leading anchor tag a tthe front of each line.

Comment: @casper: have you read my answer?  have you tried it?

Comment: the if statement is fine, except that at the time it is reached on a line with an `<A>`, the string is like `<A HREF="...` with no second `"`, so the regex doesn't match.

Answer (score 4):

Your script is only reading one line at a time; the ending `"` is only encountered on the following iteration of the while loop.  If you want to read one link at a time, try adding:

```
local $/ = '</A>';
```

before the while().  (See [$/](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/).)

Answer (score 1):

One solution that checks if a line begins with `<A` to append the next one and do the regular expression matching to extract first grouped expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $list = "/tmp/rawurl_list";
open( my $filehandle ,"<", "$list") or die $!; 
while (<$filehandle>) {
    chomp;
    if ( m/^<A/ ) { 
        $_ .= <$filehandle>;
        if ($_ =~ /^<A HREF="(.*)"/) {
           print "$1\n";
        }       
    }   
}
```

It yields:

```
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=20193&Template=view&TableId=1023
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=21811&Template=view&TableId=1023
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22163&Template=view&TableId =1023
tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22238&Template=view&TableId=1023
```

Answer (score 1):

replace in your code `s/\<\/A\>/\n/g;` by `s/\<\/A\>\K/\n/g;` or `s/(?<=<\/A>)/\n/g`

Since `\K` resets the match before it, your closing tag is not removed.

Note: As far i know, you don't need to escape `<` and `>`

Note2: the href part of your code works only because the dot doesn't match newlines by default `.*` match all the line, then the regex engine backtracks to find the double quote). A better way is to use a lazy quantifier instead: `<A\s+HREF="(.*?)"`. A more better way is to use `\S*` instead: `<A\s+HREF="(\S*)"` (only one backtrack step for the double quote, since an URL doesn't have white spaces inside). Or `<A\s+HREF="([^"]+)"` that avoid to match double quotes.

Comment: yeah - even when i change the regex in the if statement, it does not work. i think that that is the problem - the way that the if statement is configured.